# WP Custom Post Type Taxonomy Error from Page 2 on

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have the following setup:

1. A custom post-type “intern_post” with `slug => 'intern/post'`
2. A custom taxonomy “intern_category” with `slug => 'intern/category'` which is linked to the CPT
3. The taxonomy registration runs before the custom post type registration

The error (404) occurs when I’m trying to access the custom taxonomy archive pages  from 2 and on.

First I thought WordPress might get confused with the custom taxonomy and post-type. But the error still occurs even if I register the custom taxonomy with a simpler and unique slug…

The Query Monitor Plugin even indicates that WP recognizes the right rewrite rule(s):

```
intern/category/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$ => intern_category=$matches[1]
&paged=$matches[2]
```

*I’ve seen some similar problems where they tried to solve the issue with tons of additional rewrite rules—which in my eyes seemed pretty dirty.*

To me it seems like the rewrite rules themselves work, WP get’s all the necessary Query parameters set but still refuses to load the correct template file.

Does anyone have a clue what’s wrong here?

Comment: Have you updated the permalink from Setting=>Permalink?

Comment: Can we see the actual URL to which you are getting the error? (e.g. example.com/intern/category/ .... )

Comment: @MohammadAshiqueAli yes, of course I did.

Comment: @Jamie_D E.g. example.com/intern/category/term/page/2. example.com/intern/category/term/ itself works perfectly fine.

Comment: Most likely a trivial and obvious question, but are you flushing the rewrite rules database  after making any rewrite changes? (i.e. Select Settings -> Permalinks and just click Save Changes without any changes)

Comment: @Jamie_D Right, as mentioned before I’m always updating the rewrite rules.

Comment: Is `&paged=$matches[2]` correct? I Would think  `&page=$matches[2]`  would be the correct match or am I missing something?

Comment: @Jamie_D Well that’s what WP is generating. Same query argument is used for other taxonomy archive pages which are not using the “intern/” part in their slug — and it’s working perfectly fine there. It’s a pretty weird behavior.

Comment: My guess is you have a SEO plug in that is altering the pages URL. this was a huge issue for a while with Yoast. The other thing that could be happening is a left over htaccess file that is giving the 404 from a security plug in.

Comment: Negative. Neither am I using a SEO plugin (on my local development environment), nor am I using a security plugin. I deactivated all unneccessary plugins with no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Is this from the homepage or happening on custom page? If the later, what is the name of the page?

Comment: @David.J I cannot tell you as it’s not a public page.

Comment: I am still trying to be helpful... Sir, are you using this plug in to do the WP Custom Post Type? Or did you mod a  theme yourself? https://github.com/torounit/custom-post-type-permalinks/issues/85#issuecomment-364580446

Comment: @cruzquer - I don't need the URL. Be sure the page name is not the same as the custom post type name.

Comment: @David.J Thanks for your advise. But both names do not interfere.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a slash in the slug. See [Slug Formatting : Acceptable Characters](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149191/slug-formatting-acceptable-characters).

I also wouldn’t use dashes, but underscores instead. It used to cause problems, though it might work with recent versions of WordPress.